# How to open 'window.open' in wkwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cordova, wkwebview

I developing hybrid app using cordova . . .
I write below code in `WkWebvieUIDelegate.m` 
I can open a tag (target _blank with new window) 
and i can see `NSLog` this code

But i can't open `window.open(...)` in javascript and i can't see `NSLog`

how can i open `window.open`

```
- (WKWebView *)webView:(WKWebView *)webView createWebViewWithConfiguration:(WKWebViewConfiguration *)configuration forNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction windowFeatures:(WKWindowFeatures *)windowFeatures
{
    webView.UIDelegate = self;
    webView.navigationDelegate = self;
    webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = YES;


  webView.configuration.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = YES;


    NSLog(@"1");
    NSURL* url = [navigationAction.request URL];
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];


    if ([app canOpenURL:url]) {
         NSLog(@"2");
        [app openURL:url];
    } else {
//        if (!navigationAction.targetFrame.isMainFrame) {
//
//            [webView loadRequest:navigationAction.request];
//        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the WKWebView implementation (`usewkwebview=yes`) of the existing [Cordova InappBrowser plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create an extension on WKWebView that defines a 'runJavaScriptInMainFrame:' method. In the extension method, use NSInvocationOperation

> The NSInvocationOperation class is a concrete subclass of NSOperation
>   that you use to initiate an operation that consists of invoking a
>   selector on a specified object. This class implements a non-concurrent
>   operation.

to call the undocumented '_runJavaScriptInMainFrame:' method.

```
 extension WKWebView {
        func runJavaScriptInMainFrame(#scriptString: NSString) -> Void {
            let selector : Selector = "_runJavaScriptInMainFrame:"
            let invocation = NSInvocationOperation(target: self, selector: selector, object: scriptString)
            NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperation(invocation)
        }
    }
```

Now call this one:-

```
webview.runJavacriptInMainFrame:(scriptString: "Write Particular javascript code")
```

Comment: ls it work javascript in event listener ? my javascript is in event listener ... @Deviyani Swami

Comment: You need to implement the WKScriptMessageHandler protocol to receive the message.

Comment: func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print("message: \(message.body)")
        // and whatever other actions should be perform.
    }

Comment: Sorry but don't have idea, this one is for iOS.